# How to find duplicates regardless case sensitive from oracle collection using SET operator

Tags: oracle, plsql

I knew that using SET operator we can ignore or find the duplicate vales from pl sql collection.  As per my knowledge,  SET operator will find the duplicates with same case only(All the values in either lower pr upper case).  It would be great if anyone can explain how to find duplicates regardless case sensitive.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type lt is table of varchar2(10);
  3    l_col lt := lt ('A', 'A', 'B', 'a', 'b');
  4    l_set lt;
  5  begin
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Original -----');
  7    for i in l_col.first .. l_col.last loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line(l_col(i));
  9    end loop;
 10
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Set ----------');
 12    l_set := set(l_col);
 13    for i in l_set.first .. l_set.last loop
 14      dbms_output.put_line(l_set(i));
 15    end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
Original -----
A
A
B
a
b
Set ----------
A       --> this "A" is "duplicate" of ...
B
a       --> ... this "a"
b

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

One option (to get rid of those duplicates) is to switch to case-insensitive *search* option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_comp = linguistic;

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_sort = binary_ai;

Session altered.
```

Now, running the same PL/SQL code, the result is:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type lt is table of varchar2(10);
  3    l_col lt := lt ('A', 'A', 'B', 'a', 'b');
  4    l_set lt;
  5  begin
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Original -----');
  7    for i in l_col.first .. l_col.last loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line(l_col(i));
  9    end loop;
 10
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Set ----------');
 12    l_set := set(l_col);
 13    for i in l_set.first .. l_set.last loop
 14      dbms_output.put_line(l_set(i));
 15    end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
Original -----
A
A
B
a
b
Set ----------
A               --> no more duplicates
B

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT]**

Regarding your comment about not being able to *alter session* within the stored procedure (package, whatever), well - you can do that, using dynamic SQL. Here's a demonstration (note lines 6 and 7):

```
SQL> declare
  2    type lt is table of varchar2(10);
  3    l_col lt := lt ('A', 'A', 'B', 'a', 'b');
  4    l_set lt;
  5  begin
  6    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_comp = linguistic';
  7    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_sort = binary_ai';
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Original -----');
 10    for i in l_col.first .. l_col.last loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_col(i));
 12    end loop;
 13
 14    dbms_output.put_line('Set ----------');
 15    l_set := set(l_col);
 16    for i in l_set.first .. l_set.last loop
 17      dbms_output.put_line(l_set(i));
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /
Original -----
A
A
B
a
b
Set ----------
A
B

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If you don't want to do that, I suppose that you'll have to "export" collection contents into a table (could be even a global/private temporary table, depending on database version you use), eliminate duplicates there and populate the collection with distinct values only.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think i could not able to user case insensitive search option at session level, because i need to have a logic inside packaged stored procedure, which will accept collection of string values and populate into table. Currently there is no logic to valid if the input array contains any duplicates, So duplicate values are getting populated into table.

Comment: I want to avoid duplicate values storing into table.
I have a requirement as below. If the array contains values like ABC.com, Abc.com, abc.com, XYZ.com,xyz.com, EFG.com i need to retain lower case values if it has duplicates otherwise i need to retain the case of string value which doesn't have duplicates. Expected values are abc.com, xyz.com and EFG.com(doesn't have duplicate). Is it possible in pl/sql?

Comment: You're welcome. I modified my answer, have a look, please.